# Where can I send my program for evaluation and criticism?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

Where can I send my program for evaluation and criticism?

Recently I have finished my primitive console string calculator. It is my first largest program (400 lines) on C in comparison with training programs and "hello world".

I think I must not send my program here, then where?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Good question -- but somewhat off topic. Stack Overflow Meta is the place to ask such things (or, better yet, search for an answer before asking).

Comment: Sure, Code Review does what its name promises, but don't expect to be able to dump a 400-line program and get any meaningful feedback. Ask a very specific question, preferably focused on a handful of lines of code.

Comment: Please don't dump 400 lines into a question on Code review.  Obviously some of your code is clear and easy to read/understand.  And some of it you are worried about.  Isolate the stuff you're worried about.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already sent it there before I saw your comment. Now I'll know. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you didn't read the page you were linked to. [Please read it again](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Read also [How do I ask a good question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What especially seems to be missing from your question is what parts of the code exactly you want other users to look at. It's never too late to edit your question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want people to comment on it and review like a traditional code review go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as per the on-topic page there:

> If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code
>   from your project in the following areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> then you are in the right place!

If your program does not work (i.e., you need help with a specific error or cannot get it working correctly) use Stack Overflow.

Comment: Don't answer clearly off-topic questions.

Comment: This answer is very misleading.  The question here is asking about reviewing an entire program.  Code Review is about "a specific working piece of code from your project".  An entire program is certainly not specific.

Comment: And "and you just want an answer fast" is not relevant to how Stack Overflow works.